# A curve segment which you can not define the length

Tags: real-analysis

Let L be a straight line segment on the X axis of the XY plane.

Let H be an ambient isotopy on the XY plane.

In detail, all point will not be changed its x coordinate all the time during H.

Can H take L to some L2 so that you cannot define the length for L2 or L2 has the infinite length?

If some points are unclear, let me correct them.

Thank you in advance

My original definition.

A curve segment L has the infinite length if and only if:

for all finite length d, there are some subset K of L such that:

the length of K = d

A curve segment L is said you cannot define the length if and only if:

L has no finite or infinite length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand: Sure, let $L=[0,1]\times\{0\}$ and let $H(x,y;t)=\left(x,y+tf(x)\right)$ where $f$ is a continous function that is not of bounded variation on $[0,1]$. For example, $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I ask which condition this L2 does fall of; you cannot define the length for L2 or L2 has the infinite length?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the distinction between the two. What definition of length are you using?

Comment: Let me define my version of the distinction and let me write it on the question area above. So please answer to many of us who cannot understand why your function is not defined the length.

Comment: Oh okay, in that case, the length of L2 is infinite.

Comment: Really? I 'm very surprised. Thank you very much. I learned a lot this time.